# Line magic function `%%time` not found

Tags: python, jupyter, magicline

Running this python script

```
%%time
train_data = dt.fread('../input/prediction/train.csv').to_pandas()
```

The provided output returns this error:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%%time` not found.
```

Please suggest some approach.

Answer (score 67):

`%%time` is a 'cell magic' and has to be the first thing in the IPython (Jupyter) cell.  I can reproduce this error if for example I have a comment first.  When `%%time` is not the first thing in the cell, IPython tries to interpret it as a 'line magic' hence the error you see.

I took a quick look in the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#magic-command-system) and it's not made explicitly clear there as far as I can see.

Comment: `%%time` was the first thing in the cell, but after going through the documentation, I wasn't able to understand where I was wrong.

Comment: having the same issue., using vscode interactive window

Comment: @ChandrachudPati Perhaps Simon mean that %%time should first line in your cell where you are using it. If there is any other line before this code then it will throw an error. Anyways I used %time and found it works well even if it is not the first line in cell.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use %%time at top line of the cell in a notebook. Else it would throw the error.

Comment: Hi there - welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [answer]. This question was asked almost two years ago, and your answer gives the same information as is provided in the top-voted answer. If you think additional information or context would be helpful, feel free to add it! But providing duplicate answers isn't helpful. Also, be sure to check out the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) to ensure your inline code and code blocks are legible. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

`%%time` was the first thing in the cell and after going through the documentation i found `%%time` is now updated with `%time`

Comment: `%time` is not the same as `%%time` because the former only see's how long the current line takes to execute, whereas the latter checks the how the current line and following lines take to execute.