# UsageError: Line magic function `%%time` not found for cosine similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Despite there are quite a few posts on SO but none of the answers explains my situation.

When I ran this code in Jupyter Lab (on Windows 10) cell

```
%%time
a = 1
time.sleep(5)
```

I got this output `Wall time: 5.01 s`

But when I ran another code in the next cell

```
%%time
cosine_similarity(dt, dt) # dt is a sparse matrix of type <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I got this error `UsageError: Line magic function` %%time `not found.`

This is so bewildering. Could someone please explain what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful

[Line magic function `%%time` not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124633/line-magic-function-time-not-found)